# Is there way to obtain words from a tweet that aren't used to filter tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am streaming tweets using Tweepy filtered by these tags ["corona", "quarantine", "covid19"]

If I have this tweet for instance, "I fell down the stairs and ate an apple so no doctor #quarantine"
I would like to get strings like "stairs", "apple", and "doctor" as a set of keywords

Is there any way to do this?

I am a beginner at python and I am using video tutorials on Youtube to start this project

```py
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    lis = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, lis)

    stream.filter(track=['covid19','corona','quarantine'])
```

Comment: What you could do is: set up a json file (or some other config file) with your keywords. Then when you get "stairs", "apple", "doctor", etc, update the file with your new keywords. Meanwhile, have your streamer poll the file every x time (every hour, 6 hours, five minutes, etc) and update its internal keyword list with the file's keyword list and restart the streamer.

Comment: @asuprem that's not what I'm looking for... I intend to stream live tweets and for each tweet I would like to extract words that have value when conducting an analysis...I don't want to add to the list of tags to filter tweets by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
tags =  ["corona", "quarantine", "covid19"]
tweet = "I fell down the stairs and ate an apple so no doctor #quarantine"

# print each word in the tweet that is longer than two characters and
# does not contain any of the tag words
print([word for word in tweet.split() if len(word) > 2 and not any(tag in word for tag in tags)])
```

This isn't a perfect solution, mainly because it excludes words that *contain* a tag, i.e. if one of the tags were `wash`, then the word `washington` would be excluded.  But it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? -

If you want to break the tweet into words then -

```
s =  'fell down the stairs and ate an apple so no doctor #quarantine'
allwords = s.split(' ')
allwords

#output
['fell', 'down', 'the', 'stairs', 'and', 'ate', 'an', 'apple', 'so', 'no', 'doctor','#quarantine']
```

Then you can separate the words with # tag by doing this -

```
hastags = [i for i in allwords if i[:1]=='#']
hastags

#output
['#quarantine']
```

Next you can filter our the words that have # tags by doing this -

```
otherwords = [i for i in allwords if i not in hastags]
otherwords

#output
['fell', 'down', 'the', 'stairs', 'and', 'ate', 'an', 'apple', 'so', 'no', 'doctor']
```

For larger datasets and a long list of specific hashtags i would recommend doing this -

```
tags = ["corona", "quarantine", "covid19"]
[i for i in s.split(' ') if i.strip('#') not in tags]

#output
['fell', 'down', 'the', 'stairs', 'and', 'ate', 'an', 'apple', 'so', 'no', 'doctor']
```

If you have a situation that the tags used to filter the tweets may NOT have a # in front of them but you still want to filter them out then -

```
tags = ["corona", "quarantine", "covid19"]
print([i for i in s.split(' ') if i.strip('#') not in tags and i not in tags])

#output
['fell', 'down', 'the', 'stairs', 'and', 'ate', 'an', 'apple', 'so', 'no', 'doctor']
```